# Jasmine JSON fixtures VS service mocking

Tags: angularjs, json, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Assume we have a service which calls api and we use this service to do some logic in a controller.
What is better to use?

```
user = $injector.get('userSrv');
var myFixture = angular.fromJson(window.__html__['mydata.json']);
$httpBackend.whenGET('url/').respond(myFixture);
user.getGender();
```

or just using

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.service('userSrv', function(){
        return {
            getGender: function(){
                return 'something';
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Both should be used, but in different tests.

In controller spec, a service is supposed to be mocked, because the unit under test is a controller.

In service spec, http request is supposed to be mocked, because the unit under test is a service (this allows to keep the test synchronous and independent from the backend, it is not possible to perform real requests with ngMock any way).

This allows to unambiguously determine which unit failed when a test becomes red.